# Uninitialized constant (Name Error) creating object

Tags: ruby

I am trying to instantiate a new object by calling another class but I keep getting this error and I don't know why. I am still new to Ruby so I might be missing something here. I am getting this error:

```
TestA.rb:3 in `initialize': uninitialized constant TestA::TestB (NameError)
    from TestA.rb:7:in `new'
    from TestA.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

Here is my code: ** These two classes are in separate files **

```
class TestA
    def initialize
        @test = TestB.new
    end
end

test = TestA.new

class TestB
    def test_method
        print "Hello"
    end
end
```

Comment: you should require file that contains `TestB` class in `TestA` file

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I didn't know you had to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to require file with test_b class definition. If its name is `test_b.rb` it will looks like:

```
require_relative "test_b"

class TestA
    def initialize
        @test = TestB.new
    end
end

test = TestA.new
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. So you have to list every file that you plan on using? Why don't you have to do this in Java?

Comment: You have to - `import` statement resolves it for e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html